# Changing Database From Postgre To MySQL In Laravel App Leads To Timeout/Symfony Exception

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, symfony

Haven't found anything helpful on the net.

I couldn't get Postgre running on a Plesk Cloud Server so I tried switching to MySQL on my windows development system.

I changed the corresponding entries in .env and database.php and uncommented the mysqli/pdo_mysql lines in php.ini.

mysqli seems to not working at all since it leads to Query/PDO Exception/"could not find database driver", same as if there was no mysql extension active at all.

pdo_mysql gives a change but leads to a timeout followed by a long html output, starting with

```
 Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalErrorException (E_UNKNOWN)
```

Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded

and focused on

```
C:\Users\....\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connectors\Connector.php


    /**
     * Create a new PDO connection.
     *
     * @param  string  $dsn
     * @param  array   $config
     * @param  array   $options
     * @return \PDO
     */
    public function createConnection($dsn, array $config, array $options)
    {
        list($username, $password) = [
            $config['username'] ?? null, $config['password'] ?? null,
        ];

        try {
            return $this->createPdoConnection(
                $dsn, $username, $password, $options
            );
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            return $this->tryAgainIfCausedByLostConnection(
                $e, $dsn, $username, $password, $options
            );
        }
    }
Arguments
"Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded"
```

Apache error.log looks clean. MySQL dlls are present in /ext. With postgre everything worked fine. Maybe someone has an idea before I setup everything anew. Thanks

Comment: I'm guessing that your connection attempt is throwing an exception. Is `tryAgainIfCausedByLostConnection` just going to keep on trying to connect? That's probably why you are getting the time out. Check your connection.

Comment: Also why are you using the null coalesce operator: `??` on your username and password? Those are required to connect so shouldn't the absence of those values throw an error instead of just using null?

Comment: The source is Symfony code. I have no insight there. It spits out a stacktrace with 91 items. First time that I have that Symfony error instead of the usual formatted Laravel error page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the problem was the port number still set to postgre in .env.
Laravel apparently tries to establish a connection initially even when there is no database access on the page.